# how to change thousands line of number to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got thousands lines of number

```
142156
108763
77236
78186
110145
126414
115436
133275
132634
......
82606
```

and I wanna change it to an array [142156, 108763, 108763, 77236, 78186, ....]

If I could make all these number assigned to a variable, I could choose either to use the RegExp     or to convert to string first and then array.
any idea how to make it as a variable or other better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read as string from file then split the string at line breaks and map the resultant array of strings to number

```js
const str = `142156
108763
77236
78186
110145
126414
115436
133275
132634`;

const arr = str.split(/\r?\n/).map(Number)

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Depending on the provenance of the source string, it might be delineated by `CRLF` (i.e. it was read from a Windows text file). As such, a more robust split would be `str.split(/\r?\n/)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method.

```js
const nums = document.getElementById("numbersDiv").innerHTML;

const numsToArr = nums.split('\n').map(Number)

console.log({ numsToArr } )
```

```html
<div id="numbersDiv">142156
108763
77236
78186
110145
126414
115436
133275
132634</div>
```